# NullReferenceException during C++ callback to C# function

Tags: c#, c++, callback, marshalling, nullreferenceexception

developers!
I have very strange problem. My project has DLL writen in C++ and a GUI writen in C#. And I have implemented callback for some interoperability. I planed that C++ dll will call C# code in some circumstances. It works... but not long and I cant understand why. The problem marked in comment in C# part
Here the complete code of simplified sample:

C++ DLL:

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                    LPVOID lpReserved
                                    )
    {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" 
{    
    typedef void  (*WriteSymbolCallback) (char Symbol); 
    WriteSymbolCallback Test;

    _declspec(dllexport) void InitializeLib()
    {
        Test = NULL;
    }

    _declspec(dllexport) void SetDelegate(WriteSymbolCallback Callback)
    {
        Test = Callback;
    }

    _declspec(dllexport) void TestCall(const char* Text,int Length)
    {
        if(Test != NULL)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<Length;i++)
            {
                Test(Text[i]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

C# part:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CallBackClient
{
    class Program
    {
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate void WriteToConsoleCallback(char Symbol);

        [DllImport("CallbackSketch.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void InitializeLib();

        [DllImport("CallbackSketch.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void SetDelegate(WriteToConsoleCallback Callback);

        [DllImport("CallbackSketch.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void TestCall(string Text,int Length);

        private static void PrintSymbol(char Symbol)
        {
            Console.Write(Symbol.ToString());
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitializeLib();
            SetDelegate(new WriteToConsoleCallback(PrintSymbol));

            string test = "Hello world!";


            for (int i = 0; i < 15000; i++)
            {
                TestCall(test, test.Length);// It crashes when i == 6860!!!! Debugger told me about System.NullReferenceException
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it crashes in 6860th iteration! I believe that the problem is lack of my knowlege in the subject. Could sombody help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
       SetDelegate(new WriteToConsoleCallback(PrintSymbol));
```

Yes, this cannot work properly.  The native code is storing a function pointer for the delegate object but the garbage collector cannot see this reference.  As far as it is concerned, there are *no* references to the object.  And the next collection destroys it.  Kaboom.

You have to store a reference to the object yourself.  Add a field in the class to store it:

```
    private static WriteToConsoleCallback callback;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeLib();
        callback = new WriteToConsoleCallback(PrintSymbol);
        SetDelegate(callback);
        // etc...
    }
```

The rule is that the class that stores the object must have a lifetime at least as long as native code's opportunity to make the callback.  It must be static in this particular case, that's solid.