# Convert object to void* and back?

Tags: c#, c, interop

I'm trying to write a wrapper around a [C function](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/SDL_AddEventWatch) that expects a function pointer and arbitrary user data (`void*`). The function pointer I've figured out how to deal with using delegates, but I can't figure out how to convert an `object` into a `void*`.

I can make it a `ref object` instead, since that behaves like a pointer AFAIK, but when I try that I get an exception like

> An invalid VARIANT was detected during a conversion from an unmanaged VARIANT to a managed object. Passing invalid VARIANTs to the CLR can cause unexpected exceptions, corruption or data loss.

[This "solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10119332/65387) might work for me, but I figured there has to be a way to pass arbitrary data to a C DLL so that it can be passed back later?

Comment: Personally, I think you'd do better to use a pointer to a `struct` via a `fixed` block...

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: The C DLL will take an `IntPtr` no problem, but how do I turn it back into an `object` when it returns then (and also how do a 'cast' an object to an IntPtr)?

Comment: @Mark like this? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a8d37fb.aspx

Comment: @MarcGravell: So I should disallow passing arbitrary objects? I guess that could work. I have no explicit need for objects at the moment, just trying to make the API as friendly as possible. The "fixed" bit does raise another question, but I'll ask that separately.

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: That just turns an `IntPtr` into an `int`...

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would advise using a `struct` here, which is much more applicable for what you are trying to do (plus you can tweak the internal layout if you need). For example, with a `struct Foo`, and a *field on a reference-type* `foo`:

```
unsafe void Bar()
{   
    fixed (Foo* ptr = &foo) // here foo is a field on a reference-type
    {
        void* v = ptr; // if you want void*
        IntPtr i = new IntPtr(ptr); // if you want IntPtr
        // use v or i here...
    }
}
```

Note: if `foo` is a *local variable*, then it is on the stack and doesn't even need to be `fixed`:

```
unsafe void Bar()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Foo* ptr = &foo; // here foo is a local variable

    void* v = ptr; // if you want void*
    IntPtr i = new IntPtr(ptr); // if you want IntPtr
    // use v or i here...
}
```

Comment: A question about the second bit -- if `foo` is on the stack, won't it be popped off the stack at the end of the function, thus leaving the C DLL with a dangling pointer?

Answer (score 2):

If am not mistaken I think you need `Pointer.Box` and `Pointer.UnBox` methods.
These methods help to box and unbox the unmanaged pointer.
Check out [Pointer.Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.pointer.box.aspx) and [Pointer.UnBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.pointer.unbox.aspx) at msdn.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, this sounds backwards. `Box` expects a "supplied unmanaged memory pointer". The C DLL has *not* supplied me with a `void*`, I need to generate one to pass to it. And I'm fairly certain `Unbox` will fail unless the `object` was boxed first.

Comment: what is the actual type of `userdata` you want to pass?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: `object`. It's whatever the user wants to have passed back to him when the callback is invoked -- it can be anything.

Comment: It will be value type or?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Not necessarily, no. I guess I could limit it to value types if I had to, but the C API accepts anything, and I wanted to make my wrapper as flexible as possible.